# Angular & Redux - effects or multiple actions in reducers

Tags: angular, redux

If I search for "how to dispatch multiple actions" or "how to return multiple actions in effects" I find the answers, what I am unclear about is what the best way to approach this is.

I have an Angular application with Redux, with lots of actions/effects/reducers etc. these are my options (Please excuse the lame choice of example naming)

Option 1:

```
Component dispatches "GoSomewhere"
Component then dispatches "CloseSomething"
Reducer reacts to "CloseSomething" and sets "Closed" to 1
```

Option 2:

```
Component dispatches "GoSomewhere"
Reducer reacts to "GoSomewhere" and sets "Closed" to 1
Reducer reacts to "CloseSomething" and sets "Closed" to 1 (Even though not called in this case)
```

Option 3:

```
Component dispatches "GoSomewhere"
Effect reacts to "GoSomewhere" and dispatches "CloseSomething"
Reducer reacts to "CloseSomething" and sets "Closed" to 1
```

Comment: Is there an actual sideeffect handled in Option 3 within Effects?

Comment: Yes there will be